# my Bootstrap4 Flip Card not work correctly in iphone browsers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have created css3 Flip Card on bootstrap4. it works fine in desktop browser and android but in iphone devices when flip occurs the card will disappear suddenly.

```
``
```

http://codepen.io/salehi186/pen/ObdmBX?editors=1100

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpgzLW?editors=1100

Comment: Have you ever checked it in iphone???!!